# Can I read settings in BIOS without restarting Ubuntu

Tags: power-management, bios

Can I read my bios settings under Ubuntu without restarting?

For example, I'd like to check the sleep settings in my BIOS, S3 (suspend) or S4 (hibernate). As of now, I can't hibernate, and am troubleshooting. If the BIOS is already set to S4, then I don't bother rebooting to enter the BIOS. 
I'd prefer not to reboot, as I have other programs running.
Also, I'd like to have internet access, so that I can Google the settings I don't understand or can't find, and rebooting leaves me no browser.

Lastly, I'd like to know if it's possible to change my BIOS settings without rebooting?

Comment: Please don't use the distribution tags (e.g. "Ubuntu") unless your question is somehow _specific_ to that distribution. The fact that you happen to be using it is not reason enough to tag it so.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course not of them :

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# biosdecode 
# biosdecode 2.12
ACPI 2.0 present.
    OEM Identifier: DELL
    RSD Table 32-bit Address: 0xCAFAD028
    XSD Table 64-bit Address: 0x00000000CAFAD078
SMBIOS 2.6 present.
    Structure Table Length: 2331 bytes
    Structure Table Address: 0x000EBA00
    Number Of Structures: 57
    Maximum Structure Size: 247 bytes
PNP BIOS 1.0 present.
    Event Notification: Not Supported
    Real Mode 16-bit Code Address: F000:BFF6
    Real Mode 16-bit Data Address: F000:0000
    16-bit Protected Mode Code Address: 0x000FC01E
    16-bit Protected Mode Data Address: 0x000F0000
PCI Interrupt Routing 1.0 present.
    Router ID: 00:1f.0
    Exclusive IRQs: None
    Compatible Router: 8086:27b8
    Slot Entry 1: ID 00:1f, on-board
    Slot Entry 2: ID 00:1d, on-board
    Slot Entry 3: ID 00:1a, on-board
    Slot Entry 4: ID 00:1b, on-board
    Slot Entry 5: ID 00:16, on-board
    Slot Entry 6: ID 00:04, on-board
    Slot Entry 7: ID 00:1c, on-board
    Slot Entry 8: ID 00:01, on-board
    Slot Entry 9: ID 00:06, on-board
    Slot Entry 10: ID 03:00, slot number 33
    Slot Entry 11: ID 05:00, slot number 34
    Slot Entry 12: ID 0b:00, slot number 10
    Slot Entry 13: ID 11:00, slot number 18
    Slot Entry 14: ID 01:00, slot number 16
    Slot Entry 15: ID 00:02, on-board
    Slot Entry 16: ID 09:00, slot number 9
    Slot Entry 17: ID 00:00, on-board
```

How to write to bios:

Sppose you set date such as :

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen# date -s "Sun May 10 04:42:12 IRDT 2015"
Sun May 10 04:42:12 IRDT 2015
root@debian:/home/mohsen# hwclock  -w
```

Then you can write your changes on bios with `hwclock -w`

Comment: which item is for sleep mode?

Comment: All of sleep mode are rekated to your kernel support, test it.But biosdecode is limit and read only.

Comment: Does this work with EFI firmware?

Comment: Yes, it does. For more information : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface

Comment: Is that all we can get?